# Keeping variables in both data tables using SQL in HIVE

Tags: sql, hive, where-clause

How do I keep the variables in data0  from both data1 and data2 after selecting only the cpt code existing in data2?

data1 has variables: ID age year cpt_code1 cpt_code2

data2 has variables: gender clinic cpt_code

Desired result: after selecting matching cpt codes between data1 and data2, data0  also keeps all the variables from data1 and rest of the variables from data2 after only desired cpt codes were selected. It would look like this:

data0: ID age year gender clinic cpt_code1 cpt_code2

```
CREATE  (TABLE data0  as
      SELECT * 
        from 
                data1
      where 
     cpt_code1 in (select cpt_code from data2) 
     OR 
 cpt_code2 in (select cpt_code from data2)                              
);
```

Comment: Sample data and desired results would clarify what you want.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you are looking for LEFT JOIN.
Try something like:

```
SELECT d1.ID, d1.age, d1.year, d1.cpt_code1, d1.cpt_code2, d2.gender, d2.clinic
FROM data1 d1 LEFT OUTER JOIN data2 d2
ON d1.cpt_code1 = d2.cpt_code OR d1.cpt_code2 = d2.cpt_code
```